# Toolbar in Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, interface, storyboard, design-guidelines

I am new with IOS interface designing and I am curious about if I can put toolbar in tab and if this would no be against guidlines. What I am trying to accomplish is to have two tabs with toolbar that saves data, erase and quick load (same for both tabs).

I am wondering also how to do that visually, if I should put section on top of view with tabs and toolbar on bottom, or stack it on bottom.

I am using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Navigation Controller as a toolbar with your Tab bar controller.

**Easiest way for this is the follow**:

1. Create a new project in Xcode as a Tabbed Application
2. Go to Storyboard
3. Select "First View Controller" and go to Editor - Embed in Navigation Controller
4. Select "Second View Controller" and go to Editor - Embed in Navigation Controller

I dont think placing a toolbar directly above tab controller is following Apple's HIG:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-views/action-sheets/